# WCF Data Contract Data Member with Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract

I have a data contract that looks something like this:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "MyResult", Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
    public class MyResult
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "MyValues", Order = 3)]
        public Dictionary<string, object> MyValues { get; set; }
    }
```

When I populate the object in the Dictionary with simple types like string, int etc.. there is no problem.  If I put more complex objects in there such as List (of strings), I get the following error:

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to --http://localhost:8081/externalwsapi. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

This error doesn't make sense, I am of course using Http binding.  I believe I have a serialization error, but how to make it work?

Comment: You do have a serialization problem. "object" is not serializable. The following link has info on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx

Comment: @Klinger nailed it. You cannot WCF needs to know what it is deserializing. Object, being the base of most everything, cannot be serialized. Just like you can't serialize a Hashtable. Is there a way you can narrow the scope?

Comment: What you have to keep in mind is that the other side needs to know what to deserialize the payload to. So, even if you are able to serialize, and deserialize, you would have to code what to "cast" the object to, what means that you know ahead of time what the payload is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have dealt with this issue by changing the signature from object to byte[] and doing the serialization myself. I think I used JSON.NET for that. It's been a while now.

Then, on the caller side, I deserialized the payload to what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use object as the type in your collection, WCF serializer can't know what type it can be, so it can't serialize the collection.

You can use KnownTypeAttribue to indicate which kinds of object may be stored in the collection.